# How to find out if a Timer is running?

Tags: .net, timer

If I have an instance of a System.Timers.Timer that has a long interval - say 1 minute, how can I find out if it is started without waiting for the Tick?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

`System.Timer.Timer.Enabled` should work, when you call "Start" it sets Enabled to TRUE, "Stop" sets it to FALSE.

Comment: will it check and work for all the running instances of `Timer`? also the one created at runtime or by creating a new object of Timer class, it would be great if you would help me.

Comment: will this property check work with `Systems.Windows.Forms.Timer` or only with `System.Timer`?

Answer (score 21):

```
if (timer1.Enabled)
{
   // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 14):

If Timer.Enabled is true, your timer is running.

Calling Timer.Start sets Enabled to true.

Calling Timer.Stop sets Enabled to false.

If Timer.AutoReset is true, then Enabled will automatically be set to false the first time the timer expires.

Comment: The remark about the behavior of AutoReset is wrong. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): true if the Timer should raise the Elapsed event each time the interval elapses; false if it should raise the Elapsed event only once, after the first time the interval elapses. The default is true.

Answer (score 8):

Use the timer's [*Enabled*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled.aspx) property.

Answer (score 3):

You should check that timer is enabled

Comment: Because your answer is in a form of question.