# Determine if Timer is running

Tags: c#, timer, system.timers.timer

In this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150575/how-to-find-out-if-a-timer-is-running) it shows how to determine if a timer is running. For me it is not working.

I have the timer declared in a static class as shown

```
public static class ServiceGlobals // Globals
{

    public static System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
}
```

}

On Start-up of my service, I set the timer properties

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {                  

                    ServiceGlobals._timer.AutoReset = false;
                    ServiceGlobals._timer.Interval = (3000);
                    ServiceGlobals._timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
                    ServiceGlobals._timer.Enabled = true;
                    ServiceGlobals._timer.Start(); // Start timer                  
        }
```

then i check if it is running in one of my methods but even when it is running the code is always false

```
if (ServiceGlobals._timer.Enabled) // Check if the timer is running
{
    // Return error.........

}
```

Comment: Try this and see what it returns. `ServiceGlobals._timer.Enabled = true;if (ServiceGlobals._timer.Enabled){}`

Comment: Side note: 1.You shouldn't expose public fields. 2.Non public members should have "PascalCase" naming convention with no prefixes.

Comment: We could already tell from your previous question that your Interval property is too short.  So yes, very high odds that you'll get *false* because the Elapsed event handler is running.  No guarantee however.  Use a bool variable to keep track.  And note the inevitable race condition, stopping the timer doesn't stop the Elapsed event handler from running nor does it prevent you from enabling the timer again.  If you are sick of this class yet then [have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033431/17034).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have missed this part of the thread you linked:

"If Timer.AutoReset is true, then Enabled will automatically be set to false the first time the timer expires."

Comment: but i have Timer.AutoReset set to false

Comment: I see that.  So Enabled will NOT be set to false automatically.  So you can't use it to see if it is running.  Maybe you need to see if the function the timer executes is running, or have the function set Enabled to false.

Comment: Ok i understand what you are saying now.

Comment: I misspoke in my previous comment, you CAN use Enabled to see if the timer is running when AutoReset is false...it's always running...it'll always be true.

Comment: So in my function should i set ServiceGlobals._timer.Enabled = false; and at the end of the method ServiceGlobals._timer.Enabled = true; ? This is going to look messy.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do.